# Pointer Syntax Within Condition

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement

After a pointer is initialized, do you have to use the * dereference operator to call the pointer in a condition?

Example:

```
int main()
{
    int var = 10;
    int *ptr = &var;

    if(ptr)    // does this need to be if(*ptr)  ???
    {.......}
}
```

And can I have a short explanation as to why?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to check whether the pointer is non-null or do you want to check if the _contents_ of the pointer are non-zero? The answer to that determines whether you need `if (ptr)` or `if (*ptr)`.

Comment: `if(ptr)` is often used instead of `if(ptr != nullptr)`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is good to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (ptr)
```

check if the pointer is not `Null` but

```
if (*ptr)
```

check if the value it points to is not zero (in this example is 10)

So for checking the value you shoud add *.

Comment: Okay, thank you. This is exactly what I needed. I am just trying to get the hang of pointers and references. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.

`if(ptr)` checks if the pointer value is `nullptr` or not. Note that this is shorthand for `if(ptr != nullptr)`.

`if(*ptr)` checks if what the pointer *points to* is `nullptr` (or 0) - and in that case, since you dereference (follow) the pointer to answer the question, the pointer itself had better *not* be `nullptr` in that case.

Comment: So, if I’m understanding this correctly, dereferencing the pointer (*ptr) will check the condition as if I used if(var), whereas NOT dereferencing (ptr) will check to see if the pointer is null or actually holds a legal memory address?

Comment: @Hill3D That's correct. Except that `if(ptr)` will only tell you if the pointer is `nullptr` or not, it does *not* verify if the address it holds is *valid* or not, just that it is not `nullptr`.

Comment: thank you! Much appreciated. This is my first time using Stack Overflow and I gotta say, the response time of everyone has been wonderful! Thanks again!

Comment: @Hill3D You are welcome. Btw; the usual way to say "thank you" for an answer that helped you is to upvote it. No need for thank you comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a pointer is only a variable. However, there are different contexts in which you can use it.

As any other variable you can access the pointers content (which is the adress of the underlying memory) as follows:

```
int i = 1;
int * p = &i;
std::cout << p << std::endl
```

this would output the adress of `i` since this is what is stored in `p`

If you however want to access the content of the underlying memory (the value of `i`), you need to dereference the pointer first by using the `*` operator:

```
std::cout << *p << std::endl;
```

This would print the value of `i`so `1`.

of course you can also access the pointer's adress (since the adress of `i` is a numeric value as well and needs to be stored somewhere too):

```
std::cout << &p << std::endl;
```

That would output the adress of `p` so the adress where the adress of `i` is stored :)
As a little example try to run this code:

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    int i = 1;
    int * p = &i;
    std::cout << "Value of i(i): " << i << std::endl
              << "Adress of i(&i): " << &i << std::endl
              << "Value of p(p): " << p << std::endl
              << "Dereferenced p(*p): " << *p << std::endl
              << "Adress of p(&p): " << &p << std::endl
              << "Dereferenced adress of p(*(&p)): " << *(&p) << std::endl;
}
```